# Why do my blocks not have a baseFeePerGas property?

Tags: gas-price, clique

I've got a private network that's using the clique consensus protocol and is running using Geth (if that's relevant).

I have been confused about gas and transaction fees, so wrote a script to look at how the fees change given the [gas] size of the previous block.  I ran my script on the Rinkeby network to try it out, and what I saw aligns with what I expected.  (If the block is >100% of the target size, I expect the `baseFeePerGas` to increase; if it's <100% I expect `baseFeePerGas` to decrease.)

However, when I run the same script on my private network, the `baseFeePerGas` property is missing from every block.  Given that my network and Rinkeby use the same protocol, is it unreasonable of me to expect the same properties on blocks?

Currently my network is completely suboptimal in that it only has one miner.  Could this be why `baseFeePerGas` is missing?

**UPDATE:**

Geth version is `1.10.16-stable-20356e57`.

My `genesis.json` is:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 21456,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 600,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5eccf14a",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f1bfa564d354a59ca9c71e606c8f19eae19d52cb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "1000000000",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    ...252 others...
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ff": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000211184408e571bdb4fd96f1815f515e7b2a03": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "1081d21e1e6bcb3e71bcf025305e80f68e45351d": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "702e36767e3c5298c91160c5716ea0d9c807a881": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "793c20626b11a569460186e803a32391bc759ff9": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "f1bfa564d354a59ca9c71e606c8f19eae19d52cb": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

I've trimmed it to get rid of an excessive number of accounts.

Comment: What's the geth version used? Can you share your genesis file?

Comment: @Ismael I've updated the question to include that information.

Comment: The property `baseFeePerGas` was introduced in [EIP-1559](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107173/how-is-the-base-fee-per-gas-computed-for-a-new-block) at the London hard fork. You've to upgrade the blockchain adding LondonBlock to the configuration.

Comment: Many thanks, @Ismael.  Is it possible to do that on a running blockchain, or will I have to delete all the data and let it start again?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See here for a recent answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78616/it-possible-to-hard-fork-a-private-network-without-resyncing-chain-from-scratch.

Comment: Turns out I also had to add `berlinBlock` as well as `londonBlock` to the `genesis.json` file; seems can't have the latter without the former.

Comment: @Ismael If you want to write an answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It will be better if you write the answer with the new genesis config section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @Ismael for the guidance, here's a trimmed version of my `genesis.json` file:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 21456,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 150,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

The relevant bits are the inclusion of `londonBlock` and `berlinBlock`.  (I also changed `period` from 600 to 150, but that's unrelated.)